# Autenticação basica usando AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

Como posso fazer uma autenticação basica HTTP usando AFNetworking em Objective - C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem como [outras publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AFNetworking) encontradas por aqui, a requisição é bem semelhante. Você só vai precisar acrescentar no `requestSerializer` os dados de autenticação através do método `setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername`.

Em geral, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"usuario" password:@"senha"];

[manager GET:@"http://..." parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Obrigado Paulo.